# Django: Access each form and FileField in formset

Tags: django, file, loops, formset

How can I iterate thorugh a formset to get each form and FileField for in that form?

```
for file in formset.files:
 ....

for form in formset.forms:
 ....
```

I'd like the above in the same loop since I need both of them in the same time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, but if you're looking for your form object and uploaded file in the same loop, it would look like so:

```
    # code
    for form in formset.forms:
        form.is_valid() # objective #1 accomplished
        the_file = form.cleaned_data['my_file_field'] # objective #2 accomplished
```

If not, please clarify.

Comment: not sure if this works though because it will look for '0-my_file_field' and '1-my_file_field', etc... unless it only does that because I am setting a prefix on my forms...